# Flash issue on Internet Explorer

Tags: flash, internet-explorer

I've just added a flash application to my web app. And from time to time, I get emails from users (very rarely though) with screenshoot and information that they don't see flash. I've investigated that those users have flash plugin installed, and they can see flash in other browsers.

On the screenshoot there's blank white space instead of flash - no messages on bars that flash plugin is missing, nor information in place where flash should appear. Some of those users were accessing my application within PC located inside company. Is it possible that it's some kind of browser policy is blocking the flash?

Appart from that , is it possible to provide user with a message if flash is blocked somehow or no flash plugin is installed?

Thanks, Pawel

Comment: Do you have a URL we could look at?  This might just be an error in the HTML...

Comment: If they refresh the page does it work?  I've seen that and have no explanation for why it happens sometimes.  Usually only the first time they try to load Flash on that particular page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after having a conversation with two people, it turned out that they didn't have flash installed + they were using combinations of virtual machines with browser emulations etc.... Anyway, to make things clearer for me and users I switched from putting **object** element directly into page to [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) library. Since then, I had no issues. Users see flash control or my div content with message...